# XML с одинаковыми тегами

Tags: wordpress, xml, excel

Есть вот такой код.
Пытаюсь привести его в доступный для импортирования в WordPress.
Пытался экспортировать его в Excel, чтобы получились столбцы с тегами и в строчке были все параметры.
Но столкнулся с тем, что для тега, к примеру `<param name="Короткое описание">`, Excel не создает отдельный столбец, а лепит все в кучу еще и в разные строки.

Есть ли какой-то способ, например, либо переименовать  допустим в param1 и закрыть его таким же тегом, либо как-то объяснить Excel'ю, что это разные столбцы.
Таких offer очень много, вручную - не вариант

```
<offer> 4271</offer>
<param name="Короткое описание">Колготки женские TRENDY MELANGE 60, р.2, chocolate</param>
<param name="Материал">полиамид 50%; полиэстер 38%; эластан 12%</param>
<param name="Размер">2,3,4</param>
<param name="Цвет">chocolate,grafit,grey,melanzana,verde</param>
<param name="Плотность">60</param>
<price>235</price>
```

Comment: Для импорта из xml в ВП есть плагины.

Answer (score 1):

Импорт в Ecxel проще всего в форме csv - та же табличка. 
Будет как-нибудь так:

```
    offer   price   Короткое описание   Материал    Размер  Цвет    Плотность
    4271    235 Колготки женские TRENDY MELANGE 60, р.2, chocolate  полиамид 50%; полиэстер 38%; эластан 12%    2,3,4   chocolate,grafit,grey,melanzana,verde   60
    4271    235 Колготки женские TRENDY MELANGE 60, р.2, chocolate  полиамид 50%; полиэстер 38%; эластан 12%    2,3,4   chocolate,grafit,grey,melanzana,verde   60
```

Для преобразования xml->csv я использую XQUERY. Для Вашего примера можно сделать, например, так [пример xml в  csv средствами xquery](https://gist.github.com/kontur32/1984ee5ecf194f718e8b9210bf29577a).

В Excel будет выглядеть [так](http://prntscr.com/n8xqpx).

Для обработки xml в качестве xquery-процессора использую [BASEX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9365810/simple-tool-to-learn-xquery). У него есть GUI +  очень удобные средства для публикации в виде API.